# What is the best event to fire page based auto interactions in Smartphone, using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I went trough, [jquery .live() event interactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405483/jquery-live-event-interactions) and  [What event does JQuery $function() fire on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908724/what-event-does-jquery-function-fire-on) i dint get write answer, so thought to go new,

1. I have list of different pages as follows

   - Index(terms and conditions)
   - Login
   - Splash
   - Dashboard
2. I have validations in index page and login page.
3. I have used one more jQuery file called, validation.js which is linked to all pages. I have placed all the validations inside

   $(document).ready(function() {

   });
4. I have validations in index page and login page.
5. When site navigation, validations are not fire, but if I place validations

   $('div').live('pageshow',function(event){

   }

then it works.

Just want tto verify.

- Is this correct, if not please suggest me.
- document.ready as in jQuery, what is the best in jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume best solution is,

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event){

}
```